# How to resort a collection in Java?

Tags: java, geotools

I try make a project to write data from .mif/.tab files to Data Base using GDAL/OGR. I do:

```
SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(dbFeatureType);
SimpleFeatureCollection collection = FeatureCollections.newCollection();
while (mifReader.hasNext()){      
  in = (SimpleFeatureImpl) mifReader.next();
  SimpleFeature dbFeature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
  for(AttributeDescriptor ad : adList){
    String name = ad.getLocalName();
    Object attrValue;
    attrValue = in.getAttribute(name);
    if(attrValue instanceof String){
      String string3 = new String((attrValue.toString()).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "cp1251");
      if(name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(kadname.trim())){
        dbFeature.setAttribute("kadnum", string3);
      }
    }
    if (attrValue instanceof Geometry){
        idn++;
        com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry geom = (Geometry) in.getAttribute(name);
        dbFeature.setAttribute("id", idn);
        System.out.println("after insrt="+idn);
        dbFeature.setAttribute("deleted", deleted);
        dbFeature.setAttribute("the_geom", geom);
        dbFeature.setAttribute("status_id", status_id);

    }
    collection.add(dbFeature);
    }
}
```

Its simple data from .mid file:

```
__id_|___kadnum_____

  3,"66:2:00:88 951"
  4,"66:2:00:88 952"
  5,"66:2:00:88 954"
```

And in db i get this:

[image]

My data is 2-4 rows. You see that i get increment variable `idn` and put it in attribute `id`. Take a `kadnum` from .mid and put it in attribute `kadnum`.
Its fine but in bd i get rows in the wrong order. I mean that element with attribute `kadnum=66:2:00:88 951` gonna be in second row in db but it in 4th row.
 Its mean that i gonna change the order of items in the collection to the opposite. Its right solvetion? And how to do this? Or GDAL can do it by self?

**UPDATE**

I have:

```
 SimplePropertyImpl in =(SimpleFeatureImpl) mifReader.next();
```

I try:

```
in.getProperty("id").getName() ;
```

And i dont get a PropertyName i get a String. What i doing wrong?

Comment: Databases in general don't guarantee that rows are stored in a particular order. If you want to get the rows from the database in a particular order, use an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to sort the database rows according to `id`?

```
select * from <yourtable> order by id asc;
```

If you want to sort your `FeatureCollection` in code, you may want to look into [SimpleFeatureCollection.sort](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/simple/SimpleFeatureCollection.html#sort%28org.opengis.filter.sort.SortBy%29) and [SortBy](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/filter/sort/SortBy.html). I would expect something like

```
collection.sort( new SortBy() 
                 { 
                     @Override PropertyName getPropertyName() { return YourPropertyNameImpl( "id" ); } 
                     @Override SortOrder getSortOrder() { return SortOrder.ASCENDING; }
                 }
```

would get you started in the right direction.

Cheers,

Comment: Hi, i want to sort collection. But i cant find how to use sortBy.

Comment: in this line ` @Override getPropertyName() { return "id"; } ` error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to PropertyName`

Comment: I did write "...get you started...", you should do some work yourself :-)

Comment: A method sortBy `The type SortBy is deprecated`.

Comment: See http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/filter/SortBy.html (*Please use org.opengis.filter.sort.SortBy*)

Comment: Wht is it `YourPropertyNameImpl( "id" );`? I cant find anything about propertyname.

Comment: That would indicate that *you* need to write *your own* implementation of PropertyName to tell the sort algorithm which property *you* want to sort on.